# Is it possible to send fax over dsl in mac os x

Tags: mac, fax

I was wondering if its possible to send fax on dsl internet connection, because i dont have dial up modem in my macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly send faxes using dsl.  There are a number of electronic fax services available online though, and many of them have free trials too, so if you only need to send one or two that might suit you.

Alternatively USB fax modems are fairly inexpensive.